# Using Excel to Sum Ranges of Cells That Meet Certain Criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, do-while

Here is a better update.  I've included a screenshot that illustrates what I am trying to do.  I am trying to write a function that does this automatically instead of me having to do it all manually.

[image]

---

I have an Excel sheet that contains 6,568 rows of data.  For one of the columns, E, I am trying to create subtotals for all of the times that the flow rate drops below 5.  I have included a screenshot as an example.[image: Flare Data]

What am I trying to do is create a function that scans the entirety of column E and sums up the times (column A) for when the value of column E is below 5.

I thought I could do this when an IF statement, but I do not think that is the best way.  Maybe "SUMIF", but I don't think that is right either.  Is this something better suited for VBA?

This is what I started with:

```
IF(E2270<5, IF(E2271<5), blah blah blah)
```

I am a little stumped here though.  Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot with headers

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to sum.  Is it the number that appears in column E, or do you want to count the number of times column E is less than 5?  Have you tried something like =COUNTIF(E:E,"<5") or =SUMIF(E1:E7,"<5")?

Comment: What I need to sum is the time.  So, I need to get the periods of time where the flow rate is below five and report how long it was below 5.  Does that make more sense?

Something like this: "the flare was not in operation during the following times: one hour from 10:25 to 11:25, 4 minutes from 13:02 to 13:06", that kind of thing.

Comment: a little.  Including the headers in your screenshot would be more helpful. Column A isn't a time, so I don't think you can sum that. Also, summing times doesn't seem overly helpful.  Do you want to sum the difference in two time points?  Something like If E2270 is less than 5 calculate the time difference between C2270 and F2270.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for time ranges here.  So, I need to report all of the times where the flare was not in operation (for simplicity we're saying that's when the flow rate is below 5) and the duration of each time frame where the flare was not operating.

I went back and included a screenshot with headers.

Comment: ok. getting closer.  Let's focus on your 2nd screenshot.  Starting at line 2 (which is 0).  The next time the data is 5 or greater is line 28.  So you want to know the difference between F2 and F28?  That works out to be 0.036111 days, which should be converted to something more useful, like minutes...And do this for the whole range, adding the time calculation up as you go.  Is that about it, or have I missed the mark completely?

Comment: Yes that sounds correct.  Basically, I'm looking to find ALL of the ranges of times where the flow rate drops below 5.  Federal regulations require that all of the periods of time where the flare isn't operating for more than an hour need to be reported, including the length of time the flare was not operating.  I'll worry about the more than an hour part later.  But for now, I need to scan all of column E for periods of time where the flow rate is less than 5.

Comment: ok, I think I got it. I'm at the end of my day here so can't work on it now.  If no one chimes in, I'll see if I can't give you something later.  For what it's worth, I think your question can be cleaned up a little based on what we went through in the comments section.  I doubt most people will read our mini-novel, so may want to edit the question again and get the important bits in there.

Comment: **Here is my suggestion:**  
Create a new column (K), that show the duration between periods.  
For example: Cell "K2" value `=C3-C2` and scroll it down to the bottom of your table. Now Column K will have the duration, which we can easily sum with the following formula: `=SUMIFS(K:K,E:E,"<"&5)` 
You may want to encapsulate your duration formula with  `=IFERROR(C3-C2,<enter default duration value here>)`, since the very last entry won't have a duration value.  
And you can also get units of measurements for your results like so `=HOUR(SUMIFS(K:K,E:E,"<"&5)) =MINUTE(SUMIFS(K:K,E:E,"<"&5))`

Answer (score 0):

### Here's what I think you're looking for:

[image]

### Couple columns:

**Col C. Less than 5?**

```
=IF(B2<=5, C1+1, 0)
```

This is a helper row that counts the number of cells since we've entered a <5 period. This will help us create the ranges that we need.

**Col D. Is the last?**

```
=IF(AND(C2>0, C3=0), 1, 0)
```

This is just a simple boolean for if this is the end of a period and thus we should do calculations.

**Col E. Sum of Flow**

```
=IF(D2=1, SUM(OFFSET(B2, -1*(C2-1), 0, C2, 1)), "")
```

If this is the end of the period, then sum the flows from the current time period to the start of the period. We do this by doing a range of `Col C. Less than 5?` rows and 1 col starting from the top most small value to our current value.

**Col F. Time of Flow**

```
=IF(D2=1, A2-OFFSET(A2, -1*(C2-1), 0), "")
```

This is similar to Col E. If the time interval is consistent, then you can just multiply the time interval by `Col C` instead of subtracting.

You can now hide `Col C` and `Col D` as they don't need to be displayed.